# inserting a mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->query('select
  sum(like) as atotal
from
  like
where
  sfid = '.$short);<br>
print_r($query);
```

and the error is

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'like) as atotal from like where sfid = 11' at line 2
>
> select sum(like) as atotal from like where sfid = 11
>
> Filename: C:\wamp\www\don\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

'like' in sum(like) is column name and 'like' after 'from' is table name
thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You chose my answer then you changed you mind. Mine was first after all, see the timestamps. Oh well, what can you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use **like** keyword in your query. 
It is sql-specific word treated as special keyword. To solve this task, you should change column name in database table or wrap like keyword in backticks either:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select sum(`like`) as atotal from `like` where sfid = '.$short);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$data = array(
              "category_id"=>$this->input->post('category'),
              "name"=>$this->input->post('name'),
              "description"=>$this->input->post('descri')
              );

    $this->db->insert('measurement', $data);
    $inserted_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 3):

`like` is a MySQL reserved word

- **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html**

which needs to be wrapped in backticks.

Either do that, or rename your table/column to something else.

Using reserved words is discouraged to be used. You can use them, but require special attention.

- I suggest you rename your table to `likes` and your column to another word.

If renaming them isn't an option, then modify your code to read as this:

```
$query = $this->db->query('select 
  sum(`like`) as atotal 
from 
  `like` 
where 
  sfid = '.$short);
print_r($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use it. Just use **`like`** instead of **like** OR change the table name. The backQuote helps to override the MySql keyword override.